# python multiprocessing about string statistics

Tags: string, multiprocessing

I have a file format as below:

```
45  TCGGCGCAGCGTTAGGATTAG 44    TTTCATCTGCCGCCGTTGCCG
43  CGTTTTCGGATGGATCATTGT 43    CTTGCGACGCATTTGGATCAG
35  CCGATTGCTAATCGGCAGTTG 32    TCGCGGTATCCGTCTCTTAAT
31  TTTAATGCTAAGACTACGTGG 31    TTGTGGGTGCATCAGGATTTG
31  ACTTGGCTGGCTAATGTGCAG 31    CGTTCTCTGCGGATTTATCAG
31  TCGCCGACGCCTTATTGTAAT 30    ACGAAGCCTTAGTGGATGCTT
15  ACGATGATGATGCCTCATCTT 3     ATTACTGAGCTTAAGGCGAAG
```

It has 10 million rows, first column is occurrences and second column is DNA sequence. I want translate the DNA to peptide first. Then I want calculate the overall occurrences of 20 amino acid in 7 positions(column), overall occurrences of 400 amino acid pairs in 6 positions, overall occurrences of 8000 amino acid trimer in 5 position, and overall occurrences of 160000 in 4 positions.
Here is my codes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#!/usr/bin/env python
def fre(aa,cn):
    import numpy as np
    m=len(aa)
    position_monomer=np.zeros((m,7))
    position_dimer=np.zeros((m,6))
    position_trimer=np.zeros((m,5))
    position_tetramer=np.zeros((m,4))
    fre_monomer=np.zeros((20,7))
    fre_dimer=np.zeros((400,6))
    fre_trimer=np.zeros((8000,5))
    fre_tetramer=np.zeros((160000,4))
    aa_default=['A','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','K','L','M','N','P','Q','R','S','T','V','W','Y']
    for i in xrange(m):
        for j in xrange(7):
            position_monomer[i][j]=aa_default.index(aa[i][j])
            fre_monomer[position_monomer[i][j]][j]=fre_monomer[position_monomer[i][j]][j]+cn[i]

    for i in xrange(m):
        for j in xrange(6):
            position_dimer[i][j]=20*aa_default.index(aa[i][j])+aa_default.index(aa[i][j+1])
            fre_dimer[position_dimer[i][j]][j]=fre_dimer[position_dimer[i][j]][j]+cn[i]

    for i in xrange(m):
        for j in xrange(5):
            position_trimer[i][j]=400*aa_default.index(aa[i][j])+20*aa_default.index(aa[i][j+1])+aa_default.index(aa[i][j+2])
            fre_trimer[position_trimer[i][j]][j]=fre_trimer[position_trimer[i][j]][j]+cn[i]

    for i in xrange(m):
        for j in xrange(4):
            position_tetramer[i][j]=8000*aa_default.index(aa[i][j])+400*aa_default.index(aa[i][j+1])+20*aa_default.index(aa[i][j+2])+aa_default.index(aa[i][j+3])
            fre_tetramer[position_tetramer[i][j]][j]=fre_tetramer[position_tetramer[i][j]][j]+cn[i]

    return fre_monomer,fre_dimer,fre_trimer,fre_tetramer 

#!/usr/bin/env python
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
from Position import fre
from Xdelete import X_delete
from Bio.Seq import translate
import time

start=time.clock()
textfile = open(r"C:\Users\Shangyang Li\Desktop\FINAL 8 DATA SETS\illumina_phd7_allseqs.txt","r")

data = []
copy_number=[]
DNA=[]
peptide=[]

for line in textfile:
    data.append(line.split())

for row in range(len(data)):
    copy_number.append(int(data[row][0]))
    DNA.append(data[row][1])

peptide=[translate(line) for line in DNA]
(peptides,copy_numbers)=X_delete(peptide,copy_number)

(fre_monomer,fre_dimer,fre_trimer,fre_tetramer)=fre(peptides,copy_numbers)
```

But I want get the frequency of monomer,dimer,trimer,tetramer as faster as possible, now is 30 minutes to 10 million data size. I want use multiprocessing to deal with this problem, but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to combine some of your loops. If two outer loops are making the exact same iteration, combine their inner loops to avoid the outer iteration:

```
for i in xrange(m):
    for j in xrange(7):
        ....

for i in xrange(m):
    for j in xrange(6):
        ....
```

Becomes:

```
for i in xrange(m):
    for j in xrange(7):
        ....
    for j in xrange(6):
        ....
```

Also, see if you can avoid some of the `index()` calls, as they often have to iterate over the whole list under-the-hood.

Comment: Got it. But I think it is not fast enough. Could I use multiprocessing to deal with it?

Comment: Sure. Once the data is read in by the main thread, you could fire off threads to calculate each of the separate statistics. A quick [Google search for "python threading"](http://www.google.com/search?q=python+threading) yields plenty of helpful results.

Comment: Could you give me some hints about the codes, I already search it in Google, still have no idea....

Comment: How can I avoid the index, that is the only way I find...for dimer trimer and tetramer.